# Как запустить Celery через Docker

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, celery

Пишу сайт на Django, появилась потребность в асинхронных задачах, взялся за Celery. На локальном сервере всё работает корректно, но столкнулся с проблемой при переносе.

При запуске worker'а на боевом сервере через Докер выскакивает ошибка:
celery -A crm_transfer wokrer -l info

```
Usage: celery [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Error: Invalid value for '-A' / '--app':
Unable to load celery application.
The module crm_transfer was not found.
```

Вот код:

docker-compose.yml

```
celery:
  container_name: 'avihovalot.celery'
  build : .

  command: celery -A crm_transfer worker -l INFO
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  links:
    - redis
  depends_on:
    - redis
    - django
```

celery.py

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'crm_transfer.settings')

app = Celery('crm_transfer')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

**init**.py

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app', )
```

settings.py

```
REDIS_HOST = '0.0.0.0'
REDIS_PORT = '6379'
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0'
```

Структура:

```
crm_transfer:
    -crm_transfer:
        -init.py
        -setting.py
        -celery.py
    -api:
        -tasks.py
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8
```

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV TZ=Europe/Kiev

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gcc g++ cmake clang python3-dev python-dev 
python3- 
pip nano \
bpython3 postgresql libgmp10-dev build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev 
ca-certificates supervisor

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python -m pip install setuptools cython
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install -r /requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install uvicorn[standard] websockets
RUN python -m pip install pgcli
#RUN daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8008 crm_transfer.asgi:channel_layer
USER root
EXPOSE 9000 8008 8001
```

Не понимаю, почему не находит воркер, ведь и в нужной директории нахожусь, и код, вроде, правильный...
За сегодня уже весь гугл перелазил - ничего(
Буду очень благодарен за помощь)

> celery==5.1.0

Comment: добавьте в вопрос содержимое Dockerfile для сервиса celery

Comment: Содержимое Dockerfile для celery? У меня в Dockerfile ничего нет для celery

Comment: зачем тогда в docker-compose.yml это ```celery:   build: ...``` ? Если у вас нет Dockerfile, то может тоогда использовать опцию image ?

Comment: Dockerfile есть, но в нём нет ничего про celery
Сейчас добавлю Dockerfile в вопрос

Comment: Добавил докер файл

Comment: у вас в Dockerfile нет копирования ваших скриптов из crm_transfer в контейнер, и в docker-compose.yml нет volume опций для монтирования этих папок со скриптами. Вероятно поэтому вы получаете ошибку Unable to load celery application. The module crm_transfer was not found.

Comment: В каком смысле - нет копирования скриптов?

Comment: Каким образом ваш  модуль crm_transfer попадает в файловую структуру вашего celery контейнера ?

Comment: Я добавил в docker-compose volumes

Comment: Изменил docker-compose

Comment: тогда наверное надо еще поменять ``` command: celery -A crm_transfer worker -l INFO``` т.к. приложение в контейнере лежит в папке app, а не в папке crm_transfer

Comment: А на что можно поменять, есть предложения? А то уже пару дней этим голову ломаю?))

Comment: вы указали в docker compose.yml что монтируете папку, в которой он лежит внутрь контейнера /app

Comment: Да, внутри /app